# How to load a Rails plugin from the site_ruby dir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a plugin (called XYZ) installed in

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/XYZ
```

Please note its not a rubygem but the "native" ruby sitelib library. Now.

I have added this line to the config/environment.rb:

```
config.gem "XYZ"
```

The problem here is Rails is not loading the plugin. Is there a trick to force loading from the ruby_site directory? Rails 2.3.10

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you make it a gem, vendor it, or put it in lib? Putting it in the core ruby folders, while in the load path, is incredibly bad practice. If it's not a gem, then why are you trying to use `config.gem` to require it?

Comment: I am using a fedora package that is built as a snapshot (the plugin has never released a gem yet). Hence the only way to package this in the linux distribution is the "native" way (ruby_site lib).

Comment: You should never have to put any libraries in the core ruby folders. Is it a rails plugin? If so, it should be vendored (put into vendor/plugins). If you really want to have it somewhere else on the system, it would be better to store it elsewhere and add that to the load path.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. I have installed a library XYZ from an RPM. Fedora Package Guidelines requires the files to be installed there. Its the correct place theres no doubt about it. All I need to know is how can I tell Rails application to load plugins from this directory. http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Ruby

Comment: My application is distributed as an RPM package. Its not possible to include 3rd party plugins in one RPM file. Thats against Fedora Packaging Guidelines (or any linux distribution packgaging guidelines). One library/program = one package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure why you're needing to do this (and I imagine there is a better way), but if this is your only option, then here goes...

Unlike gems which are just 'required', Rails loads plugins by running `eval` on the plugin's init.rb file (see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.10/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb#L158) for 2.3.10 if you're interested). The 'site_ruby' folder is in Rails' load path, but files in there will be treated as normal libraries, not plugins.

To change this, you can easily add to Rails' load paths in your app config:

```
config.plugin_paths << "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8"
```

I don't have any experience with building RPM packages, but if it's forcing you to build your app in such a brittle way, then is it really the best way to distribute it? Just a thought! :)

Comment: Thanks. Ad RPM - whole Linux Open Source world relies on the proper packaging. And the rule is one product/library = one package. Thats how it works. While most rubyists does not like to distribute their software (projects, sites) using RPM I have to do it. Again thanks.